# How to check RGB colors against a color range?

Tags: python, rgb

I am writing a python script where I need to check colour code against 3 colours: red, yellow and green in this way:

```
if (255,255,255)  is in green range:
    print("green")
else if (255,255,255)  is in yellow range:
    print("yellow")
else if (255,255,255)  is in red range:
    print("red")
else:
    print("none")
```

The thing I am having trouble is with how to see if it `is in yellow range`?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The following picture represents my sense of yellow, green and red:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "green range"? Can you define that?

Comment: it means if the color is any shade of green

Comment: yeah but I mean: say you have a color `(r,g,b)` under what conditions is it "close" to red? Should it be `(255,0,0)` only, or is `(200,10,10)` allowed as well? There was once an experiment on whether people identified a color as green or blue. Because Russian has two different words for blue (light blue and dark blue), iirc Russians saw more colors as blue. Even people do not agree on that matter, so you need to define that first.

Comment: I will edit my question with more information

Comment: edit done, please refer to it.

Comment: Well, my color picker says that the colors you've circled in the picture are (0, 255, 114), (249, 246, 78) and (255, 0, 19). So compare to those values and you're good to go.

Comment: yes, but green has different shades: for example near the edges where it meets with yellow, that is also green. so i want that wherever green is more heavy, label it as green, where yellow is more heavy label it as yellow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```py
KNOWN_COLORS = {"Red": (255, 0, 0), "Yellow": (255, 255, 0), "Green": (0, 255, 0)}

def color_difference (color1, color2) -> int:
    """ calculate the difference between two colors as sum of per-channel differences """
    return sum([abs(component1-component2) for component1, component2 in zip(color1, color2)])


def get_color_name(color) -> str:
    """ guess color name using the closest match from KNOWN_COLORS """
    differences =[
        [color_difference(color, known_color), known_name]
        for known_name, known_color in KNOWN_COLORS.items()
    ]
    differences.sort()  # sorted by the first element of inner lists
    return differences[0][1]  # the second element is the name


my_color = (123, 234, 100)

print(get_color_name(my_color))

# zero copyrights / public domain
```

Figures, `my_color = (123, 234, 100)` closest match was green :)

Comment: This works perfectly! exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Convert the colour to HSL and refer to a colour wheel like [this one](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm) to choose your definitions of yellow, red and green, specifically the H value.

Comment: Hi Rishav, the link provided gave me a virus security warning, please check if it link is still valid, thanks.

Comment: @JackDev what do you mean by a virus security warning?

Comment: on clicking the link, my antivirus software says it blocked a potential security threat from the site. Does the link you've provided still work for you?

Comment: @JackDev yes it does. And since VirusTotal reports [clean](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/9fa8b76bf9ec360d1ce64584292835b0ccdbbc864c0a8703e30b21a2fb0c75ef/detection), I’m inclined to believe your antivirus has a false positive.